# selenium firefox.get() function fails to decode response from marionette in python

Tags: python-3.x, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Using selenium 3.01 with python3.5 to firefox 4.7; `driver.get()` function does not return to main script after second fetch. Similar to question asked (Jun 16 by user6472032) 
I use `driver.get()` to initially fetch a page and complete the login. When `get()` is used to select a second page at the same remote site the page opens but the python script hangs until the page is closed manually when the shell reports this error:

```
driver.get('https://mso.morganstanleyclientserv.com/shell/account#/holdings')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 2
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 2
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", lin
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to decode response from marionette
```

Is there any alternative way to get this rather fundamental function to work twice without changing the main script?  Perhaps a different set of calls to avoid the error handler?  Thanks

Comment: use firefox>=48 with selenium 3

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you meant firefox version 47.0.0, there is this note in the [Selenium changelog for v3.0.0](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG):

```
* Firefox is only fully supported at version 47.0.1 or earlier. Support
  for later versions of firefox is provided by geckodriver, which is
  based on the evolving W3C WebDriver spec, and uses the wire protocol
  in that spec, which is liable to change without notice.
* You may wish to choose an ESR release such as 45.4.0esr or earlier.
* Firefox 47.0.0 is not supported at all.
```

This is the last mention of firefox version by which I deduce that it still applies to v3.0.2.

Bottom-line, I would heed the advice about ESR 45.4.0esr if I were you.

UPDATE: I have been looking into this more myself.  Selenium 3 introduced a dependency on the geckodriver to support firefox. The [geckodriver website](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver) has this to say, "Marionette and geckodriver are not yet feature complete. This means it does not yet offer full conformance with the WebDriver standard or complete compatibility with Selenium."  I suggest backing off to Selenium 2.53 and firefox esr 38.8.0 until geckodriver is ready for primetime.

Answer (score 2):

Was still getting this exception even when using latest versions of Firefox and geckodriver (58.0.2, and 0.19.1, respectively, at the time of writing this). Wasn't getting it with driver.get() but with driver.quit() and it was because I had closed my pyvirtualdisplay before quitting the driver.

Works:

```
from selenium import webdriver                                                       
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display                                                 

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))                                        
display.start()                                                                      
driver = webdriver.Firefox()                                                         

driver.quit()                                                                        
display.stop()
```

Doesn't work:

```
from selenium import webdriver                                                       
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display                                                 

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))                                        
display.start()                                                                      
driver = webdriver.Firefox()                                                         

display.stop()
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to reproduce the problem with Firefox 47.0.1 and Selenium 3.0.1. Try adding the below code to eliminate this error.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\SW\\geckodriver-v0.13.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();   
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", false);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```